# Python program randomly hangs up

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do some webscraping in Python, which involves accessing about 500 similar webpages for data to put in a .txt file.

However, I'm having some problems:

- The CPU usage for my program (checked through task manager) randomly drops to 0% and stays that way.
- My command prompt itself becomes unresponsive as Ctrl + C won't kill the program.
- This has occurred at seemingly random times, anywhere between the 8th webpage and the 480th.

  ```
  def getAnime():

    for index in range(2, 502):

        # gets anime statistics from HTML
        container = containers[index]
        ranking = container.td.text
        name = container.findAll('td', {'class', 't'})
        link = 'https://www.animenewsnetwork.com' + name[0].a['href']
        name = name[0].text
        statistics = container.findAll('td', {'class', 'r'})
        rating = statistics[0].text
        numVotes = statistics[1].text

        # prints out anime stats to file
        currentAnime = Anime(name, ranking, rating, numVotes, link)
        animeFile.write('\nname: ' + name)
        animeFile.write('\nlink: ' + link)
        animeFile.write('\nranking: ' + ranking)
        animeFile.write('\nrating: ' + rating)
        animeFile.write('\nvotes: ' + numVotes)

        # Goes to the webpage for the current anime
        animeClient = uReq(link)
        animeHTML = animeClient.read()
        animeClient.close()
        pageSoup = soup(animeHTML, 'html.parser')

        # Genres of the current anime
        try:
            genreDiv = pageSoup.find(id='infotype-30')
            genres = genreDiv.findAll('span')
            genreList = []
            for genre in genres:
                genreList.append(genre.a.text)
            currentAnime.genres = genreList
        except:
            currentAnime.genres = 'unknown'

        # Themes of the current anime
        try:
            themes = pageSoup.find(id='infotype-31').findAll('span')
            themeList = []
            for theme in themes:
                themeList.append(theme.a.text)
            currentAnime.themes = themeList
        except:
            currentAnime.themes = 'unknown'

        # Premiere date of the current anime
        try:
            date = pageSoup.find(id='infotype-9').div.text
            currentAnime.premiereDate = date
        except:
            currentAnime.premiereDate = 'unknown'

        # Director of the current anime
        try:
            director = pageSoup.find('b', text='Director').parent.a.text
            currentAnime.director = director
        except:
            currentAnime.director = 'unknown'

        # Production Studio of the current anime
        try:
            productionStudio = pageSoup.find('b', text='Production').parent.a.text
            currentAnime.studio = productionStudio
        except:
            currentAnime.studio = 'unknown'

        # Prints the genres
        animeFile.write('\ngenres: ')
        for genre in currentAnime.genres:
            animeFile.write(genre + ', ')
        # Prints the themes
        animeFile.write('\nthemes: ')
        for theme in currentAnime.themes:
            animeFile.write(theme + ', ')
        # Prints the premiere date, director, and studio
        animeFile.write('\npremiere date: ' + currentAnime.premiereDate)
        animeFile.write('\ndirector: ' + currentAnime.director)
        animeFile.write('\nproduction studio: ' + currentAnime.studio)

        animeFile.write('\n')
  ```

Comment: consider adding some code so it is possible to see what can be possibly wrong

Comment: I apologize for that. This is my first post on StackOverflow, and I wasn't sure if this kind of problem was even indicative of a code-related problem. I was also having trouble formatting my code

Comment: its k pal no need to apologise, we are all users here, I too was pointed out when I started

Comment: in this sort of a problem its best if you keep a little print("code is here") , you will be able to see where it froze

Comment: Noted. That did help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CTRL-C just sends a Keyboard Interrupt command to Python.](http://CTRL-C%20just%20sends%20a%20Keyboard%20Interrupt%20command%20to%20Python.) This means that when making HTML requests in BeautifulSoup, you're probably just moving up one exception level. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> will stop the program entirely.

It's likely that your script is running into a non-responsive webpage. Your CPU *would* be at 0%, because it's waiting on the web service. I suggest printing the value of `link` in your code before each `uReq` call to track where this is happening.

Comment: This does seem to be the problem. My script hangs right after the line "animeClient = uReq(link)" and the following line "animeHTML = animeClient.read()" is never completed.

However, I'm unsure how to solve this problem. Am I correct to assume this is like an unfulfilled javascript promise where it's waiting on a response form the website but never gets a response? I've tried looking up a solution but found none. Should  make a separate post about this question?

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, but I imported urllib.urlopen as uReq

Comment: I believe we've here answered your posted question. I would post a new question once you have more information about the failure itself. That way, you can scope the question to to the urllib library and instead of the body of code provided here, you can put information about the web request that's failing.